# Injecting EJB 3 into Spring Bean

Tags: spring, jboss7.x, ejb-3.1

I am trying to inject EJB into Spring (3.1.2) service (both in **different** WARs)
Both are very simple (methods removed to simplify example):

EJB:

```
@Remote
public interface MyBean {
}

@Singleton
public class MyBeanImpl implements MyBean{
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService{
}
```

At first sight thing is very simple, but I tried:

```
@EJB(lookup = "java:global/ejbApp/MyBeanImpl!com.my.MyBean")
private MyBean myBean;
```

and it didin't work. Then I also tried:

```
@EJB(mappedName = "java:global/ejbApp/MyBeanImpl!com.my.MyBean")
private MyBean myBean;
```

And

```
@Resource(mappedName = "java:global/ejbApp/MyBeanImpl!com.my.MyBean")
private MyBean myBean;
```

but neither worked.

I managed to inject my EJB  using:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="myBean" jndi-name="java:global/ejbApp/MyBeanImpl!com.my.MyBean" />
```

in my spring configuration and in the service:

```
@Autowired
private MyBean myBean;
```

But I really dont like this solution. I would like to have my JNDI path in **some** annotation to be able to do e.g:

```
@EJB(lookup = MyBean.JNDI_NAME)
private MyBean myBean;
```

Comment: Thanks Tomek :) This "somehow" solves my problem. I was aiming for some simpler solution, but if I can't just solve it with a single annotation I will try your way. I thought that it will be really easy to inject  EJB into Spring (it is THE standard after all ;) ).

Comment: Turning my comment to an answer since no one else replied.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have found quite nice and simple solution.
Into spring configuration file one has to put:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor">
    <property name="alwaysUseJndiLookup" value="true" />
</bean>
```

And that enables spring to search for the **beans** annotated with @Resource in JNDI.
So now one can do:

```
@Resource(mappedName = MyBean.JNDI_NAME)
private MyBean myBean;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you aiming to get rid of XML or to have JNDI name in annotation? If the former, I haven't tested it, but should work:

```
@Configuration
public class EjbCfg {

    @Bean
    public JndiObjectFactoryBean myBean() {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean factory = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        factory.setJndiName(MyBean.JNDI_NAME);
        return factory;
    }

}
```

Now you can simply inject:

```
@Autowired
private MyBean myBean;
```

Comment: I have never used Configuration object but I think that it would not work. The reason is that we are using Spring Portal MVC and it needs spring xml file having certain name. I've found only how to reference xml file from @Configuration object - not oposite, so I THINK this configuration won't wokr.

Comment: @MichałMargiel: it should work since `@Configuration` is discovered just like any other `@Service` or `@Repository`. But nevermind, your solution seems much simpler and cleaner, +1.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Just out of curiosity I will check it.