# Spring JNDI Lookup - can't cast com.sun.proxy.$Proxy to EJB Class

Tags: spring-mvc, jboss, ejb, jndi, wildfly

When I try to lookup an EJB from another module, jboss will return this exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy125 cannot be cast to com.foo.spring.logging.UserCategoryLogService
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:927)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:139)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:91)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146)
io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177)
io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

It looks like the the lookup is working fine so far, but I simply cannot cast the Object.
My Project is a Spring-MVC Project. The backend, which I'm connecting to receive the UserCategoryLogService from, is a simple Java-EE Project.

I tried different ways to lookup and cast. Usually I go this way:

```
try {

        UserCategoryLogService logService = (UserCategoryLogService) new InitialContext.lookup("java:jboss/exported/backend/UserCategoryLogServiceImpl!logging.UserCategoryLogService");
        logService.logLogin(username);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And usually this is working, when I'm doing local ejb-lookups in my backend project.
I also tried to create a Property and use it while creating a new Context. It will return the same error.

I added the UserCategoryLogService interface to my spring-config.xml but it wouldn't help.

I did no additional config about JNDI in spring.
I tried to lookup @Local and @Remote, both will return the same castingException.

**I'm using Wildfly 8.1.0**

Do you have any Idea how to handle the Proxy Object? And why will the ejb-lookup work with my java-ee backend but not with my spring-mvc project?

Interface of spring project:

```
import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface UserCategoryLogService {
    void logUserCatCall(String userId, Integer categoryId);
    void logLogin(String userId);

}
```

Cheers

EDIT 27.09.2014:

I found this question:
[Injecting EJB 3 into Spring Bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963405/injecting-ejb-3-into-spring-bean)

So I tried to Autowire the bean and I got the same error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'java:jboss/exported/backend/UserCategoryLogServiceImpl!logging.UserCategoryLogService' must be of type [com.frontend.spring.logging.UserCategoryLogService], but was actually of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy105]
```

Edit2:

```
 @Bean
    UserCategoryLogService getUserCatLogService() {
        UserCategoryLogService ucLog = null;
        JndiTemplate template = new JndiTemplate();

        try {
            ucLog = (UserCategoryLogService) template.lookup("java:jboss/exported/backend/UserCategoryLogServiceImpl!logging.UserCategoryLogService");
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return ucLog;
    }
```

wouldn't work either:

```
 threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy125 cannot be cast to com.recc.frontend.logging.UserCategoryLogService
```

Comment: Is this deployed as a single ear app?

Comment: 2 projects, both are deployed as .war files

Comment: This question now has a Bounty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured out, how to solve this, but I'm not sure if this is the best way.

You can use a **SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean** to lookup remote EJBS in Spring.

```
  SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean fb = new SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean();
            fb.setJndiName(UserCategoryLogService.JNDI_NAME);
            fb.setResourceRef(true);
            fb.setBusinessInterface(UserCategoryLogService.class);
            // Need lifecycle methods
            fb.afterPropertiesSet();
            fb.setJndiTemplate(new JndiTemplate());
            UserCategoryLogService logservice = (UserCategoryLogService) fb.getObject();
```

This will return the correct bean ans also won't require any additional annotations or xml configuration.

The bounty is still active. If you post a better and working way, you will receive +50 reputation.

EDIT: I'm also looking for the implementation of stateful EJBs, according to the name this will only work with stateless ejbs.